# How to update UI from rest services or servlet without request and response object?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a form which sends a post request to a servlet to download a file.The servlet further sends http request with callback url to another server. The servlet receives 202 accepted response. Servlet returns the response object displaying "Download will begin soon".
The callback url(another servlet or rest query) is called from the server and the file download begins. How do I update the UI i.e. display that File download is completed? Also as I'm using `FileUtils.copyUrlToFile()`, I cannot see that file download has been completed, but the file is successfully downloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you may be looking for: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/

You can have an event to notify the client when their download is complete which can then trigger a function to close the stream.

Comment: Thank you very much